# Is it possible to import a chunk of Js code to a file as it was already there?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a component in my app that is getting big... So I moved some chunks of code to another files (conditional and list renders to be specific).
Can I use it like a rails partial, for example? or a script tag?

I woudn't like to create a new component,it's just some code i wanna split.

of course there is a way, but do I have to import all the things (components, states, etc) to this file?
couldn't I do smt like this?

```
import myChunkOfCode from 'some/path';

// and then place it here like a script tag?
<myChunkOfCode>
```

and then this code that does not make any sense alone works pretty well when imported, without complaining about undefined stuff and etc...

Comment: The code you are trying to import, if its not a react component you could write your app logic in another file and import that in so your component is smaller.

Comment: It is app logic, but also returns some jsx

Comment: if it is app logic you can extract it into functions or class. 
if its jsx you should create component.